# Can I use std deviation on a time series?

Tags: time-series

From what I remember, std deviation is a measure of how spread apart data is from a mean.  What Im trying to do is determine whether time series data is tight enough that I can use it for proper forecasting.  Im using Linear Trend Forecasting with seasonality index to forecast my sales data and Id like to know if the data im using is "good enough"?

Comment: For a given model you can estimate the standard deviation of the forecast error. . But that doesn't say anything about the data. It just can be a measure of the usefulness of the model. If the model doesn't produce satisfactory accuracy of prediction a different model could be better. Your question needs more detail to get an appropriate answer.

Comment: OK what do you mean by more detail?

Comment: You could withhold some of the later samples and see how well they are predicted.

Answer (score 1):

It's a **rolling standard deviation** that you want - i.e. one that computes the standard deviation on a rolling basis as you move further up the time steps in the series.

The problem with time series is that the mean is constantly changing, i.e. the mean for the first 10 observations will be different from the mean for the last 10.

In this regard, if you were to compute standard deviation on a rolling basis, then this should suit your needs better.

That said, even if the time series isn't "tight enough", this doesn't necessarily mean that you cannot forecast with this. It may be the case that ARIMA doesn't give great forecasts, but volatility-based models such as GARCH or LSTM will.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm looking into lstm but it's all python stuff, command line and at best jupyter notebooks.  Do you know of any software packages that'll handle 1000 or 5000 series at a time?

Comment: What software are you currently using?

Comment: None.  I use excel for seasonality indexed linear trend forecasting and Im using command line python keras with jupyter notebooks on my Mac

Comment: Well, in terms of handling 1-5k series at a time, this is more a question of CPU and RAM capacity on your Mac as opposed to what software you use. Python or R should be suitable for what you're trying to do.

Comment: I meant ease of use.  I have about 4,000 products and I need to feed those data series into a jupyter notebook which is tedious.  I haven't really gotten to the part where I can spit those predictions into a file but even if I did, I'd have 4,000 time series files and 4,000 prediction files and each would need some unique name such as sku# and sku#prediction.  Maybe I just haven't gotten to the part where I can massively feed files and generate prediction files in batch.  I would still need to take my current data which is all in an excel file and create this individual original batch files

Comment: In terms of ease of use, the TTR package in R tends to be quite intuitive when it comes to computing rolling windows, moving averages, etc. It might be of help. Data processing is a separate issue.